# Custom Function to retrieve data from user table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, user-management

I want a write a custom function to find a particular property from identity user model.
Say I want to find a user with a specified phone number.
How to do so..???

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the UserStore class, something like below

```
public interface IUserCustomStore<TUser> : IUserStore<TUser, string>, IDisposable where TUser : class, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUser<string>
{
    Task<TUser> FindByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber);
}

namespace AspNet.Identity.MyCustomStore  
{
    public class UserStore<TUser> : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<TUser>, IUserCustomStore<TUser>
        where TUser : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser
    {
        public UserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }

        public Task<TUser> FindByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber)
        {
            //Your Implementation
        }
    }

    public class UserStore<TUser> : IUserCustomStore<TUser> where TUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual Task<TUser> FindByPhoneNumberAsync(string phoneNumber)
        {         
            return _Users.Find(u => u.PhoneNumber == phoneNumber).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }   
    }
}
```

Replace all occurrence of

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
```

with

```
using AspNet.Identity.MyCustomStore
```

And then in the IdentityConfig.cs add a new method to ApplicationUserManager

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    //LEAVE ALL THE METHODS AS IT IS

    public virtual Task<ApplicationUser> FindByPhoneNumberUserManagerAsync(string phoneNumber)
    {
        IUserCustomStore<ApplicationUser> userCustomStore = this.Store as IUserCustomStore<ApplicationUser>;
        if (phoneNumber == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("phoneNumber");
        }
        return userCustomStore.FindByPhoneNumberAsync(phoneNumber);
    }

}
```

You can now call this in the controller like

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByPhoneNumberUserManagerAsync(model.phoneNumber);
```

(assuming you have added the phoneNumber property to RegisterViewModel)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add. Answer is Updated now.